# Windows Server Scheduled Tasks not running even though it says it is

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-tasks

If I run the batch file manually it works, but when the scheduled tasks runs it (which runs every ten minutes all day long), it never runs but it says it does, there is also no errors

Here is the kicker: If I delete all the scheduled tasks, re-add them and then restart, they will work for 1-3 weeks and then randomly stop working again.

We have many servers all running the same `.bat` file, but only one of them is doing this.

Any ideas I can do or try?

Answer (score 0):

It could be the permissions or credentials that the scheduled task runs under.  At the company where I work we occasionally see that the password on the credentials has changed at a customer location.  The task needs to be updated with the new password.

Comment: i have tried that as well, like i was saying i can delete all the scheduled tasks and then re add them and do a restart and they will start working again temporalry but they always quit working within 1-3 weeks :/

Comment: thanks mike but we have the same universal password at all the locations and since i have been working here that has never changed and its only one location that is doing this,so it does have the right password